# Why was my question downvoted and closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I don't really understand why this question was closed and not even a justification given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059932/how-to-enter-password-on-terminal-using-nohup-without-disown

I have looked if I find an answer to this problem and found several other similar questions. These questions were neither closed nor downvoted and are accepted. However, since the answers were only with Linux specific commands it didn't help me, so I wrote my own question specifying that I can not use Linux specific commands.

However the question was downvoted and closed without giving an reason whatsoever, so I would know what the reason is.

Comment: Looks like an off-topic question to me, as stated in the closure reason. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: There is a close reason under the post. It is off-topic. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to be programming questions. The question does not appear to be programming related, hence closed.

Comment: The downvote is automatic, all off topic questions get a -1. If the question is re-opened, the downvote will go away.

Comment: Older questions that have not been closed might be questions that have not been closed *yet*. Don't assume that content moderation here is perfect.

Comment: Also, older questions might not have been closed because they were not offtopic at the time. Perhaps there was no suitable other subsite back when the question was asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your post was closed because there is no programming involved in the specific part you're having problems with. The actual underlying question has nothing to do with the fact that you happen to use it to run your own code.

As such the question at its core is just a generic question about how to execute a program in a certain way under HP-UX. Therefore the question belongs on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1) subsite instead of on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was not aware of that.